# JavaScript functions as expressions

Tags: javascript

I plan to use JavaScript function as expression but not successful in doing so? Can someone please help me. (Env: GoogleChrome 35.0)

```
var f1 = function(inp){console.log("INPUT - ", inp);}

f1(function(){return "HELLO";})
```

Now the output is:

> INPUT -  function (){return "HELLO";}

instead of :

> INPUT -  HELLO

Comment: you are passing the entire function reference not the value HELLO alone

Comment: You need to evaluate your function: `console.log("INPUT - ", inp())`

Comment: "// Function expressions can also be used as arguments to other functions:
data.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; });                                   Courtesy: JavaScript:The DefintiveGuide, 6th Edition

Comment: Yes, but they are useless, when noboby calls the function expression ;)

Comment: @DanLee: But that will NOT be consistent for all the types of Inputs right?                                                                  f1("HELLO")
TypeError: string is not a function                                       Checking the input type is the only option?

Comment: You are casting this function `function(){return "HELLO";}` to a string. Unsurprisingly the string representation of a user-defined function is the source code.

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol Of course this only works for function expressions, you can check the type with `typeof`.

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol: No function behaves as expected when it is called with the wrong arguments. You'd either expect a string argument or a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you define:

```
var f1 = function(inp){console.log("INPUT - ", inp);}
```

The Variable f1 references the function.
To call the function, you call f1 direct:

```
f1($param).
```

If you pass a function as a parameter, and want to invoke this function, you have to change your code to:

```
var f1 = function(inp){console.log("INPUT - ", inp());}
f1(function(){return "HELLO";})
```

Here a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGQwT/).